# No update through a service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a component(the child) inside an other component(the parent). The tag to call the child is `router-outlet`.
I wrote a service in order to the child can change a parent's variable because in this situation I cannot use `EventEmitter` and `Output` but it does not work.

The service:

```
import {Subject}    from 'rxjs/Subject';

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TabStatusService {


  private sub=new Subject<boolean>();
  dataStatus$ = this.sub.asObservable();

  changeStatus(data:boolean){

    this.sub.next(data);
  }
}
```

The parent:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers:[TabStatusService]
})


export class SecondarytabsComponent implements OnInit {


 private status:boolean=false;
  constructor(private tabStatusService: TabStatusService) {


  ngOnInit() {


    this.tabStatusService.dataStatus$.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.status = data;

      });
  }  
}
```

Template:

```
<div>



  <p>{{status}} </p>


</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The child:

```
@Component({
  ....
  providers:[ConfirmationService, TabStatusService]
})
export class ProceduresComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService, private tabStatusService:TabStatusService) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setStatus(value){
    this.tabStatusService.changeStatus(value);
  }

}
```

Template:

```
<div>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button"(click)="setStatus(true)">Back</button>

</div>
```

Where is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: "It does not work" is not a problem description. What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: I would that clicking on the child button, the "status" variable of the parent changes from false to true.

Comment: Why do you have `providers:[TabStatusService]` on every component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `[TabStatusService]` from the `providers` meta property field of your child component.

Currently you creating multiple instances of the same service. You need to provide it root component or `@NgModule` to share the same instance of the service.

If you do that it should work as expected.

Comment: @dstyle ok great, can you please accept the answer if it solved the problem for you. Thanks.